# Removing overlapping faces and internal edges from a 2d geometry

Tags: faces, edges

I have the following 2d geometry (the figure shows it in edit mode):

[image]

I need to make it a simple polygon, without the overlapping faces and the non-necessary edges (just want to keep the ones of the perimeter and holes).

How can I do that in Blender?

I've tried [this solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2Df3C3_IYE) but didn't work, also I've tried the options of dissolving vertices/edges/faces but didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on 2.79, you could use the **[TinyCAD addon](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/mesh_tinyCAD/)**:

- Make sure that all your planes are on the same level on the Z axis, if not select all and press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.
- Keep everything selected and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *TinyCAD* > *XALL*
- Only the edges remain, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.
- Delete the useless vertices with <kbd>X</kbd> > Vertices.
- Fill the faces with <kbd>F</kbd>.
- If you want to keep a central hole you need to have enough topology.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I followed your steps and now I have a clean polygon. The only problem is that I lost the holes (the big square in the center and the rectangle and small square in the upper part). Is there any way to keep the holes in the geometry?

Comment: I've edited my answer, if you want to keep a central hole you need to have enough topology.